# How to watch data changes outside the component in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, computed-properties

I want to set the `authenticated` automatically when the `this.$auth.isAuthenticated()` changes. Is it possible with `computed` or `watch`?

```js
<script>
  export default {
    data: () => ({
      drawer: null,
      dark: true,
    }),
    methods: {
      signOut: function(){
        this.$auth.destroyToken()
        this.$router.push('/')
      }
    },
    computed: {
      authenticated: function(){
        return this.$auth.isAuthenticated()
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I imagine watch and cimputed only work for properties of the component itself. You can define a custom setter in your store which emits an event when isAuthenticated changes, and listen to that event in your component.

Comment: does watching `authenticated` works ?